# What is the difference between NSS and PAM?

Tags: authentication, pam

From my readings, NSS seems to be a superset of PAM. PAM on the other hand are just limited to authentication/authorization. Am I correct ?

Comment: Does NSS handle authentication?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, PAM is concerned with authentication and authorization but not identification:

> "... you should know that PAM does not handle identification. Systems
>   that rely on PAM normally use Name Service Switch (NSS) to manage
>   identification. NSS also [like PAM] originated with Solaris, and
>   predates PAM by a few years. The lack of integration between NSS and
>   PAM has caused a continuous migraine for Unix-like systems ever since."

"Pam Mastery", Michael Lucas, chapter 0